# Format Postscript ErrorHandler

Tags: postscript

Can someone help me format the following postscript code to a readable format?  I need to modify the logic to return an error response in all conditions and never print an error page.

```
%%BeginResource: file Pscript_WinNT_ErrorHandler 5.0 0
/currentpacking where{pop/oldpack currentpacking def/setpacking where{pop false
setpacking}if}if/$brkpage 64 dict def $brkpage begin/prnt{dup type/stringtype
ne{=string cvs}if dup length 6 mul/tx exch def/ty 10 def currentpoint/toy exch
def/tox exch def 1 setgray newpath tox toy 2 sub moveto 0 ty rlineto tx 0
rlineto 0 ty neg rlineto closepath fill tox toy moveto 0 setgray show}bind def
/nl{currentpoint exch pop lmargin exch moveto 0 -10 rmoveto}def/=={/cp 0 def
typeprint nl}def/typeprint{dup type exec}readonly def/lmargin 72 def/rmargin 72
def/tprint{dup length cp add rmargin gt{nl/cp 0 def}if dup length cp add/cp
exch def prnt}readonly def/cvsprint{=string cvs tprint( )tprint}readonly def
/integertype{cvsprint}readonly def/realtype{cvsprint}readonly def/booleantype
{cvsprint}readonly def/operatortype{(--)tprint =string cvs tprint(-- )tprint}
readonly def/marktype{pop(-mark- )tprint}readonly def/dicttype{pop
(-dictionary- )tprint}readonly def/nulltype{pop(-null- )tprint}readonly def
/filetype{pop(-filestream- )tprint}readonly def/savetype{pop(-savelevel- )
tprint}readonly def/fonttype{pop(-fontid- )tprint}readonly def/nametype{dup
xcheck not{(/)tprint}if cvsprint}readonly def/stringtype{dup rcheck{(\()tprint
tprint(\))tprint}{pop(-string- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/arraytype{dup rcheck
{dup xcheck{({)tprint{typeprint}forall(})tprint}{([)tprint{typeprint}forall(])
tprint}ifelse}{pop(-array- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/packedarraytype{dup
rcheck{dup xcheck{({)tprint{typeprint}forall(})tprint}{([)tprint{typeprint}
forall(])tprint}ifelse}{pop(-packedarray- )tprint}ifelse}readonly def/courier
/Courier findfont 10 scalefont def end errordict/handleerror{systemdict begin
$error begin $brkpage begin newerror{/newerror false store vmstatus pop pop 0
ne{grestoreall}if errorname(VMerror)ne{showpage}if initgraphics courier setfont
lmargin 720 moveto errorname(VMerror)eq{userdict/ehsave known{clear userdict
/ehsave get restore 2 vmreclaim}if vmstatus exch pop exch pop PrtVMMsg}{
(ERROR: )prnt errorname prnt nl(OFFENDING COMMAND: )prnt/command load prnt
$error/ostack known{nl nl(STACK:)prnt nl nl $error/ostack get aload length{==}
repeat}if}ifelse systemdict/showpage get exec(%%[ Error: )print errorname
=print(; OffendingCommand: )print/command load =print( ]%%)= flush}if end end
end}dup 0 systemdict put dup 4 $brkpage put bind readonly put/currentpacking
where{pop/setpacking where{pop oldpack setpacking}if}if
%%EndResource
```

Comment: It looks nicer this way!

Comment: I think this question is unfairly closed. Using tools to properly indent code is absolutely on-topic for stackoverflow. The "too many possible answers" simply does not apply to this question as the available pool to tools is very tiny and I see no problem in including all of them here. I challenge anyone that thinks there exists too many options to list 10 of them.

Comment: Now for some really impressive unreadable postscript, check out http://web.mit.edu/PostScript/obfuscated-1993/Tiny_RayTracing.ps.

Answer (score 2):

That's part of the Windows PostScript printer driver prolog, and it relies on other parts of the prolog. 'Formatting' it won't help you, you'll need to effectively disassemble it in order to alter it.

However, the default error handler in your device 'probably' doesn't print an error page, so the simplest way to deal with it is just to delete it wholesale.

Comment: +1 Indeed, the sole purpose of the code appears to be printing error pages. Simplest way to deactivate it is delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken said, all this code does is print error pages. So just remove it. But, for the task of unwrapping the wall-of-code, there are options.

`indent` does a decent job of adding whitespace and brace-related indentation. It expects C code, so it throws a lot of errors. But it does break things up into something a little more readable (if you ignore or delete the indent: errors).

It erroneously adds a space between a slash and the following name, so auto-correct for that, too.

```
/ currentpacking where
{
  pop / oldpack currentpacking def / setpacking where
  {
  pop false setpacking}
if}
if /$brkpage 64 dict def $brkpage begin / prnt
{
  dup type / stringtype ne
  {
    = string
indent: Standard input:3: Error:Stmt nesting error.
indent: Standard input:5: Error:Stmt nesting error.
      cvs} if dup length 6 mul / tx exch def / ty 10 def currentpoint /
        toy exch def /
        tox exch def 1 setgray newpath tox toy 2 sub moveto 0 ty rlineto tx 0
        rlineto 0 ty neg rlineto closepath fill tox toy moveto 0 setgray show}
        bind def / nl
      {
      currentpoint exch pop lmargin exch moveto 0 - 10 rmoveto}
    def
      /==
      {
      /cp 0 def typeprint nl}
    def / typeprint
    {
    dup type exec}
    readonly def / lmargin 72 def / rmargin 72 def / tprint
    {
      dup length cp add rmargin gt
      {
      nl / cp 0 def}
    if dup length cp add / cp exch def prnt}
    readonly def / cvsprint
    {
      = string
indent: Standard input:9: Error:Stmt nesting error.
        cvs tprint ()tprint} readonly def / integertype
        {
        cvsprint}
      readonly def / realtype
      {
      cvsprint}
      readonly def / booleantype
      {
      cvsprint}
      readonly def / operatortype
      {
      (--) tprint = string cvs tprint (--)tprint}
      readonly def / marktype
      {
      pop (-mark -) tprint}
      readonly def / dicttype
      {
      pop (-dictionary -) tprint}
      readonly def / nulltype
      {
      pop (-null -) tprint}
      readonly def / filetype
      {
      pop (-filestream -) tprint}
      readonly def / savetype
      {
      pop (-savelevel -) tprint}
      readonly def / fonttype
      {
      pop (-fontid -) tprint}
      readonly def / nametype
      {
        dup xcheck not
        {
        (/)tprint}
      if cvsprint}
      readonly def / stringtype
      {
        dup rcheck
        {
          (\()tprint tprint (\))
indent: Standard input:17: Error:Stmt nesting error.
            tprint}
            {
            pop (-string -) tprint}
        ifelse}
        readonly def / arraytype
        {
          dup rcheck
          {
            dup xcheck
            {
              (
                {
                )tprint
                {
                typeprint}
              forall (}
            ) tprint}
            {
              ([)tprint
               {
               typeprint}
               forall (])tprint}
          ifelse}
          {
          pop (-array -) tprint}
        ifelse}
        readonly def / packedarraytype
        {
          dup rcheck
          {
            dup xcheck
            {
              (
                {
                )tprint
                {
                typeprint}
              forall (}
            ) tprint}
            {
              ([)tprint
               {
               typeprint}
               forall (])tprint}
          ifelse}
          {
          pop (-packedarray -) tprint}
        ifelse}
        readonly def / courier
          / Courier findfont 10 scalefont def end errordict / handleerror
        {
          systemdict begin $error begin $brkpage begin newerror
          {
            /newerror false store vmstatus pop pop 0 ne
            {
            grestoreall}
            if errorname (VMerror)
                ne
              {
              showpage}
            if initgraphics courier setfont
              lmargin 720 moveto errorname (VMerror)
                eq
              {
                userdict / ehsave known
                {
                clear userdict / ehsave get restore 2 vmreclaim}
              if vmstatus exch pop exch pop PrtVMMsg}
            {
              (ERROR:)
                prnt errorname prnt nl (OFFENDING COMMAND:) prnt /
                command load prnt $error / ostack known
              {
                nl nl (STACK:) prnt nl nl $error / ostack get aload length
                {
                ==}
              repeat}
            if}
          ifelse systemdict / showpage get exec (%%[Error:)print errorname = print (; OffendingCommand:)print / command load = print (] %%)
indent: Standard input:30: Error:Stmt nesting error.
              = flush} if end
indent: Standard input:31: Error:Stmt nesting error.
                end
                  end} dup 0 systemdict put dup 4 $brkpage put bind readonly
                  put / currentpacking where
                {
                  pop / setpacking where
                  {
                  pop oldpack setpacking}
                if}
            if
indent: Standard input:34: Error:Unexpected end of file
```